# How to write accented word with php's echo

Tags: php, special-characters

I'm creating a script to create a json file, filled with data from database.
I'm executing my script from console. Not using any kind of html.

The problem is, when I open the file, all the special characters are showed with it's code instead of the actual character.

e.g:

`sunt gre&#537;ite. V&#259; rug&#259;m s&#259;`

When I copy/pasted the string from my file HERE in stackoverflow text editor, the characters are visible, but inside my json file all i see is:

`Argil&#259; //This is what I have in database and I need to write the accented word inside my json file.`

I already tried: 
`htmlspecialchars()`, `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, `htmlentities()`.

my function:

```
   public function writeToFile($fileName, $output, $mode) {      
      $writeFile = fopen( $fileName, $mode ) or die ("Unable to open file");
      fwrite( $writeFile, htmlentities($output, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') );
      fclose( $writeFile );

   }
```

Comment: If you're executing this in a terminal, why are you running `htmlentities` at all? It doesn't feel like any function with "html" in the name is going to help you.

Comment: I'm executing the script from terminal, it's creating a json file. I'm readin this data from database which is saved with the special code instead of the accented characters. BUt you have an excelent point. So how could I convert them ? :\

Comment: I'm not sure I'm entirely following. So your data is already HTML encoded in the database? If you want to convert back to plaintext then you need to **de**code it - try `html_entity_decode`.

Comment: Updated the question with more information. What I have inside my database is `Argil&#259;` but I need to convert that code to accented character and write it inside my json file.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your data is already HTML encoded in the database, so you'll need to run it through `html_entity_decode` first:

```
$string = 'sunt gre&#537;ite. V&#259; rug&#259;m s&#259;';
echo html_entity_decode($string);
// sunt greșite. Vă rugăm să
```

To then convert to JSON, use `json_encode`. By default, this will convert any multi-byte characters to unicode escape sequences, e.g.

```
echo json_encode('sunt greșite. Vă rugăm să');
// "sunt gre\u0219ite. V\u0103 rug\u0103m s\u0103"
```

This shouldn't actually cause any problems - anything that's reading the JSON file will know how to decode these back to the correct characters, and you'll avoid any file-encoding issues causing further problems. If you know that you need unencoded characters in the output, then you can use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` constant to prevent this:

```
echo json_encode('sunt greșite. Vă rugăm să', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// "sunt greșite. Vă rugăm să"
```

Your `writeToFile` method should end up looking something like this:

```
public function writeToFile($fileName, $output, $mode) {      
  $writeFile = fopen( $fileName, $mode ) or die ("Unable to open file");
  fwrite( $writeFile, json_encode( html_entity_decode($output), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
  fclose( $writeFile );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I tried what your answer but I keep getting only the code instead of the real character. Not char what else to try =\

Comment: "JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE" works for me. I was sending an array standard as message (from API). I tried things like
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso8859');

but doesn't work. So I tried JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE and works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

try to add the following in your php file before any html is printed:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: I'm executing this  on the terminal only. There is no html, so I'm not sure where to place that meta data.

Comment: You can also try this : header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso8859-15');

I'm not sure it is works for you or not!

Comment: Already tried that.  As pointed out by @iainn, maybe there is no point using any function with `html` on it's name as I'm only writing all the data into a json file, right ? Not sure how to convert them now.